# Square root finding using prolog

Tags: prolog

I worked on following coding to find square root. But it didn't work. I couldn't find the error. Up to finding the value of Y it's working. The square root part does not.

```
print('A = '), read(A),
print('B = '), read(B),
print('C = '), read(C),
nl,
nl,
X is 2*A,
Y is (B^2 - 4*A*C),
Z is sqrt(Y),

R1 is (-B+Z)/X,
R2 is (-B-Z)/X,

print('R1 = '), print(R1), nl,
print('R2 = '), print(R2), nl.
```

Answer (score 3):

First, if you are experimenting in Prolog, refrain from using `read/1` and other side-effectful built-ins. Instead, simply type in the values you want to try out. Similarly, you do not need to print the results. Prolog's toplevel will do this for you.

```
?- A = 1, B = 2, C = 1,
      X is 2*A,
      Y is (B^2 - 4*A*C),
      Z is sqrt(Y),
      R1 is (-B+Z)/X,
      R2 is (-B-Z)/X.
   A = C, C = 1,
   B = X, X = 2,
   Y = 0, Z = 0.0,
   R1 = R2, R2 = -1.0.
```

The answer looks fine to me. But let's  look at the error you get:

```
error(evaluation_error(undefined),(is)/2).
ERROR: sqrt/1: Arithmetic: evaluation error: `undefined'
```

What the systems says here is that the value it computes for `sqrt/1` is not defined. Like in

```
?- X is sqrt(-1).
   error(evaluation_error(undefined),(is)/2).
```

The evaluable functor `sqrt/1` is only defined for floats - which are an approximation for real numbers. However, here we would rather expect an imaginary number. That's why the value is undefined.

So, to avoid that error you would have to add appropriate tests prior to `Z is sqrt(Y).`